# One of ratty girls passed away suddenly this morning. I found her in alive but unresponsive, about an hour later she had passed

Tags: health, multi-pet-families

I’m worried about her sister. Though they were independent even in cage together, they didn’t spend much time together, so I’m unsure of how she will react. I allowed her to see and sniff the body, and she did so for about five minutes and then she immediately wanted back in her cage. Tonight she appears to be looking for her sister. Any suggestions on what I can do for her?